# Persist API data in AsyncStorage React Native using Netinfo

Tags: api, react-native

I want to store the fetched API data when reopening a React Native app without internet connection.
When opening the app without internet connection, 
I use NetInfo to determine if connection is ok or not, if there is connection it shows okay, otherwise if there is no connection (offline) the load ActivityIndicator appears a little then nothing appear,

I use another logic like checking if state is null then fetch api and store data, otherwise get data from storage and this works fine, but if i relaunch the app using react-native run-android the data never appears.

This is my code:

```
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    if (state.isConnected) {
      getArticles(this.state.url)
        .then((data) => {
            // console.log('connection ok!');
            AsyncStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(data));
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
        data: data,
            });
            //DATA SET TO STATE + ASYNCSTORAGE
        })
     }
    else {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('obj').then((value) => {
          // console.log('connection not ok!');
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
            data:JSON.parse(value)
        });
      });
    }
 });
}
```

This is my code without Netinfo:

```
componentDidMount() {
   if(this.state.data=='null'){
      getArticles(this.state.url)
        .then((data) => {
            // console.log('connection ok!');
            AsyncStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(data));
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
        data: data,
            });
            //DATA SET TO STATE + ASYNCSTORAGE
        })
     }
    else {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('obj').then((value) => {
          // console.log('connection not ok!');
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
            data:JSON.parse(value)
        });
      });
    }
}
```

I added this line in android 
  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

When i console log the state.isConnected it is always true even if turn off the internet on my pc.
In case i switch off the mobile data it shows error can not connect to debbuger.